# Generate Email Alerts through Perfmon

Tags: iis-7.5, performance-monitor

I am using Perfmon to monitor the performance of my application pool. Is there a way I can generate email alerts through Perfmon if my application pool is stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Florian Sander's answer is now considered deprecated and setting up that scheduled tasks to send an email natively could or should not be done because its deprecation. Here is another way to send an email through the perfmon application.

What happens when you try to set this task up:

```html
An Error has occured for the tasks {Tasks Name}. Error message: The following error was reported: The tasks definition uses a deprecated feature.
```

The alternative:
You can achieve similar functionality by going through the steps of Florian's answer but instead of making a tasks that does the "sends out an email" action, select start a program/script. This method would require you to make a small script that would send an email for you. I included an image to help understand what you may have to do.
[Here is an image for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/462gv.png)

To include more information about my process, in my specific case scenario it was easiest to ping a web-app with certain values to email me because my server already had the capabilities to send me an email that way. I already had scripts and tasks that send me email so it was the way I accomplished that tasks. What you have to do is specific to your situation and could be entirely different way of sending the emails.

Comment: I had actually stumbled upon a howtogeek article that seems to show the same solution I came up with. Here is the link if you are still unsure on how this is accomplished
https://www.howtogeek.com/125045/how-to-easily-send-emails-from-the-windows-task-scheduler/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set up email alerts for windows performance counters. There's an instruction available from Microsoft: "[How to create performance counter alert and send email when the alert is triggered](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2424491)".

There's also [plenty of other tools](https://checkpanel.com/resources/windows-server-performance-monitoring-tools) available for monitoring windows server performance.